# Bigtable schema - multiple columns or rows?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm designing a Bigtable schema, where I am trying to optimize read performance. I'm looking for some advice on which of these 2 options would perform better:

1. Single row, with multiple columns (approximately 1-200 columns per row, with most being less than 10). The only data in each cell would be a timestamp.
2. Multiple rows for each record, with fields appended on to the row key, and just a single column for the timestamp.

I've seen some documentation recommend narrow and tall schemas, which would suggest #2. But that would require reading a range of keys to get the data back, which I presume would be slower than just reading a single row as in option 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't matter which way you do this since there would be the same amount of data stored adjacently either way. I think the single row might use less data since you wouldn't have to duplicate information about the row.

Also, since you only need timestamp data, you can use the timestamp part of the cell and make the value something that is just one byte, so you can optimize storage in that way.

Either way, it will probably be fairly negligible, but if you're concerned with latency with a few milliseconds, I'd recommend setting up a bit of data using both schemas and generating a bunch of reads on both to see if one is slightly more performant.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your read pattern. The common rule of thumb would be to
keep it together, if you access it together.

Bigtable allows you to store data in what could be considered a row or column oriented format.

If you typically read multiple attributes for an entity e.g. userid has age, address, income... then you may want to have a wide table (or you can even put all of this as a JSON in a single cell if it is infrequently updated). This would be the row oriented format (I know it is confusing because it has lots of columns). This also works well if you're reading one or more users but several columns at once.

If you read many values of a single attribute and your reads can have varying bounds e.g. assume you're reading temperatures from sensors and it could be for 3 days in one request or 3 thousand days the next, and you get it from all sensors in bulk but hardly ever anyone retrieves humidity, pressure .... columns together with temperature then you may want to choose a column oriented (tall table) layout where the rowkey might look like temperature#sensor.  Of course this doesn't necessarily mean you have to read one column at a time, you can issue multiple queries in parallel to retrieve several quickly since Bigtable can deliver high QPS.

Somewhere in between these two options is bucketing i.e. you may want to chunk the data e.g. if you know that most customers would want to get bid, ask, volume, open, close... together but within a 1 day window or increments of 1 day then you can append the date at the end of your rowkey (e.g. GOOG#20220101) and have multiple columns where each value has timestamps. This would allow you to quickly read the whole row (that contains 1 day worth of data) for multiple columns.

The performance difference may not always be huge. But for context, this happens because Bigtable is very efficient with continuous scans. So it would be faster to read A,B,C in a sequence then read A jump over several letters and then read K jump over again more letters then read Z. The tall vs wide or column vs row oriented layout gives you control over this arrangement.